# Avoiding loop when Double pressing same shortcut key without changing original 1 press shortcut key function (Autohotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

I want to produce something like this  :
1. When i press Esc 2 times (double) i want to produce my "made-up custom action"
2. When i press Esc 1 time  i want to produce the original Escape

## ok, here is the explanation of my question :

- This code should apply as global, means when i start the script it will work on all windows
- %ALAT1% is variable the Active Windows title  , abbreviation "Anime Land Akui Transform" some kind of silly anime game
- If i press Esc one time . it will "pause" the game, but when i press Esc 2 times, it will "exit" the game"
- I want to do a custom action when i press Esc 2 times, but i also don't want the original Esc key function got override when i press 1 time.

  ```
  Escape::
  if (A_PriorHotkey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400) 
  WinActivate, %ALAT1%
  IfWinActive, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass
  {
  Send {F5} ; F5 contains another action  
  }. 
  else
  {
   *Do original function of Escape i.e Send {Escape}     ; Now this is the problem    
  }
  return
  ```

after i try the code above : suppose i press "Escape" button it will loop the Escape as if i press  Escape 2 times. So my real question is how to make "original 1 times press Esc key function" won't loop to "our custom 2 times press Esc key function"  ?

Comment: I think you really should read up on the basics of AHK, the [command docs](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/) are usually a good starting point. Your code is very confusing, e.g. the `if(...)` statement will only affect the following line, and since there's neither a [block](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/Block.htm) nor indentation, it's all a guessing game. You also never mentioned that you somehow want to distinguish between windows, and the contents of `ALAT1` are unknown. I suggest you start by reading the [#IfWin..](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) docs.

Comment: @MCL eerrr i edit the question, and errr i won't need #IfWinActive if i just want to produce global action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line of your code to;

```
$Escape::
```

This will set it so that the hotkey is only triggered by real keystrokes not simulated ones.